# ASP.NET Core Windows authentication keeps asking for credentials in IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-authentication, iis-express

I am working on an app in ASP.NET Core 7 that uses the Windows Authentication and it asks for the domain credentials every single time I run the solution form the VS through the IIS Express. I run it under my domain account, so I expect it should get authenticated through it and there is no need to ask for the credentials again.

By now I tried these things, but without any success:

- `windowsAuthentication: true`, `anonymousAuthentication: false` in `launchSettings.json`
- `forwardWindowsAuthToken=true` in `web.config`
- add `https://localhost` to the Trusted sites or Intranet zone and allow authentication to the intranet zone
- `windowsAuthentication enabled=true` and both `negotiate` and `NTLM` providers in `applicationhost.config` (both in IIS Express folder and solution `.vs` folder)
- IIS options `AuthenticationDisplayName = Windows` and `AutomaticAuthentication = true` in the app builder

Nothing of these helped so far and I need to put in the credentials regardless the browser used (Chrome/Edge).

If I cancel the credential request, I get `401.2 - Unauthorized`, `You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.`

How could I get rid of it and get authenticated properly using the Windows auth?

Comment: Windows Authentication worked - you were able to connect using your Windows credentials. What didn't was the browser's Single Sign On. Even in IE it only worked with machines in the Intranet Zone. That's something that can be modified manually or through a policy. The [Windows Integrated Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-security-identity#windows-integrated-authentication-wia) section in Edge's documentation explain what's required for Edge to attempt to sign on using your account's credentials

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/windows-accounts/ppnbnpeolgkicgegkbkbjmhlideopiji

Comment: The prompt (and 401.2) is a natural part of all challenge based authentication methods (Windows/Basic/Digest). To suppress that you need to configure browsers to enable pre-authentication and the steps vary per vendor.